Is Google Maps Sdk programmatically added markers using net8 MAUI free of charge?
we have a net 8 maui mobile app for android and ios which is using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps. For android platform we have an api key obtained from google maps platform. This api key is restricted with the fingerprint obtained from the keystore sha1.
inside the app we programmatically create markers with a maui handler used to replace the default pin shape by a custom image.
Searching for information about the billing i can't find anything useful regarding map markers, only regarding map id or routing, which are functionalities that we don't use.
On the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-street-view) i've found this piece of information:

can anyone explain me this billing limit better?
if using native google maps api inside maui is indeed not free of charge, are there free or opensource alternative using like openstreetmaps or similar options that are able to programmatically add markers?
Thanks in advance.

Markers are only local and do not use a google service or anything so they have no charge to them

thank you @tyczj, can you suggest an official documentation so that I can be able to make the stakeholders of the app comfortable?

There is no official documentation, if you were required to pay it would be stated somewhere. it requires no google services to put markers on a map so therefore there is no charge

First of all, you can check the offcial document about the Android Google Map Marker. And you can add the marker by calling the platform native code.
Give a name to the Map control in the xaml:
<Map x:Name="map" ..../>

And declare the android platform method:
#if ANDROID
        public void AddMrker(double x, double y,string title,string snippet)
        {
            var googlemap = map.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap;
            var markeroption = new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MarkerOptions();
            markeroption.SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.dotnet_bot));
            markeroption.SetPosition(x, y);
            markeroption.SetTitle(title);
            markeroption.SetSnippet(snippet);
            googlemap.AddMarker(markeroption);
        }
#endif

You can copy your custom image file into the \Resources\Images\pin.png and set its buid action as MauiImage. And use it:
markeroption.SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
                              .FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

In addition, you can check the official document about the Maui Map Pins and this case about custom map pin.

thanks Liyun for the explanation of rendering a marker, but i was seeking a piece of official documentation certifying that using markers don't stack on billing.

The official document about Maps SDK for Android Usage and Billing doesn't mention the markers. But you can contact sales or contact the support team. @Gaburiere

In addition, the Google Maps Platform pricing list doesn't contain marker. So there is no official document can certifying that but the google team's response. @Gaburiere
